# WSO2 Identity Server - configure roles as separate attribute

Tags: wso2-identity-server

By default wso2 IDP returns the roles as following
 
   
   manager,Internal/identity,Internal/everyone

Is it possible to configure the IDP to return the roles as separate attribute as shown below

```
<saml2:Attribute Name="http://wso2.org/claims/role">

        <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

                xsi:type="xs:string">manager</saml2:AttributeValue>

  </saml2:Attribute>

<saml2:Attribute Name="http://wso2.org/claims/role">

        <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

                xsi:type="xs:string">Internal/identity</saml2:AttributeValue>

  </saml2:Attribute>

<saml2:Attribute Name="http://wso2.org/claims/role">

        <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

                xsi:type="xs:string">Internal/everyone</saml2:AttributeValue>

  </saml2:Attribute>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this cannot be done with WSO2 Identity Server. All the roles are returned as a comma separated list in the single "http://wso2.org/claims/role" attribute.